# How to explain that function has positive and negative values around zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have following function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\cos\left(\frac1x\right) &\text{if }x\neq0\\
0 &\text{if }x=0
\end{cases}$$

How can I prove that this function in every area of zero has positive and negative values? I thought about finding appropriate sequences, but I can't come up with idea which exactly. Could someone clue me in on good solution?

Comment: Consider $x=\frac{1}{n\pi}$ where (i) $n$ is an even non-zero integer and (ii) $n$ is an odd  integer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: as $x^2$ is always positive, show that every neighborhood of zero has a point $x$ at which $\cos(1/x)$ is negative and a point $y$ at which $\cos(1/y)$ is positive.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2$ is always non-negative. For integer $n$, when $x=\frac{1}{2n\pi}$, $\cos (\frac1x) =+1$, and when $\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}$,  $\cos (\frac1x) = -1$

So take your neighborhood of zero, take any point $p>0$ in that neighborhood, take any integer $n > \frac{1}{p}$, and the points $x=\frac{1}{2n\pi}$ and $\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}$ satisfy your conditions.

Comment: thanks, I will edit to get the $\pi$s in the correct spot in the fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy: all you need is that for every $\varepsilon>0$ you get positive and negative cosine values above $1\over\varepsilon$.

Comment: Misprint? Try $\epsilon=1/2$.

Comment: @mickep So above 2: $\cos \pi=-1<0$ and $cos 2\pi=1>0$

Comment: @mickep Oh, I see what you mean. I was too ambiguous: you get positive and negative cosine values *for arguments* above $1\over ε$.

Answer (score 0):

lets make a sequence $a_n$ such that $ n \rightarrow \infty$ then $x \rightarrow 0$

definition :$$a_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}$$   now put $a_n$ as $x$
  $$lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x^2cos(\frac{1}{x})=\\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{n\pi})^2cos(n\pi) \rightarrow 0$$ but ,note that $$x=a_n=\\(\frac{1}{n\pi})^2cos(n\pi)=\\(\frac{1}{n\pi})^2(-1)^n=\\\frac{(-1)^n}{(n\pi)^2}$$ goes to zero but alternatively $\pm$